# Place points at maximum distance in a convex 2D set

Tags: optimization, python, distance-measure

I need to place a given finite set of points within maximum distance of each other on 2D, constrained by a convex boundary, on Python.

Honestly, I'm kind of lost. I have the explicit function to be minimized, but I'm not sure which algorithm I should use to adjust the points recursively. I thought of experimenting with clustering but I'm not sure if this would work.

And, more importantly, I have no idea how to bound the space.

Unfortunately, the convex boundary isn't a rectangle as well; it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a problem in the constrained optimization class. The constraints come from the domain shape, one just needs to produce the objective function, like $\sqrt(\sum(r_i-r_j)^2/N)$, or something like that, and put it in the standard optimization solver in Python. This problem is difficult to solve for a large number of points, but perhaps some simplified formulation could be found, using the physics intuition etc. What is the purpose of this distribution of points?

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm going to use it to simulate phoneme distributions.

Comment: While it is clear what maximizing the distance between *two* points inside a (convex, bounded) region should mean, a careful definition is needed for extending this problem to more points. @Cesareo has articulated a *max-min* objective function, which seems natural and fairly robust.  But other choices are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Giving a region $\Omega(p)$ and a set of $n$ points $p_i,\ i = 1,\cdots, n$ the problem can be stated as a maximization one.

$$
\max\left(\min_{i\ne j} \|p_i-p_j\|\right),\ \ \text{such that}\ \ \forall k,\ p_k\in \Omega(p)
$$

One way to tackle this problem is by using Evolutive Strategies (CMA-ES). Follows a setup in python

```
n = 7
penality = 10000000000000


ae = 2
be = 1.1442

def feasible(x, y):
    xa = x / ae
    yb = y / be
    dif1 = xa * xa + yb * yb - 1
    dif2 = -(x + 1)

    if  dif1 < 0 and dif2 < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return max(dif1,dif2)



def objective(p):
    dist_min = 100000
    for i in range(n):
        xi = p[2*i]
        yi = p[2*i+1]
        fi = feasible(xi, yi) 
    
        if fi > 0:
            return penality
        for j in range(i):
            xj = p[2*j]
            yj = p[2*j+1]
        
            fj = feasible(xj, yj)
            if fj > 0:
                return penality
            dx = xi - xj
            dy = yi - yj
            dist = np.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
             
            if dist < dist_min:
                dist_min = dist  
            
                
    return -dist_min



import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cmaes import CMA

best_value = 100000000
best = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    optimizer = CMA(mean = np.zeros(2*n), sigma = 0.45)

    for generation in range(4000):
        solutions = []
        for _ in range(optimizer.population_size):
            x = optimizer.ask()
            value = objective(x)
            if value < best_value:
                best.append([generation,-value])
                best_value = value
                x_best = x
            solutions.append((x, value))
        optimizer.tell(solutions)
    
print(best)
print(x)

X = []
Y = []
for i in range(n):
    X.append(x_best[2*i])
    Y.append(x_best[2*i+1])

print(X)
print(Y)

angle = np.linspace( 0 , 2 * np.pi , 150 ) 

radius = 2

xc = ae * np.cos( angle ) 
yc = be * np.sin( angle ) 
xs = [-1, -1]
ys = [-1,  1]

(figure, axes) = plt.subplots( 1 ) 

axes.plot( xc, yc, color = 'b' ) 
axes.plot( xs, ys, color = 'b' )
axes.scatter(X,Y,marker = 'o', color = 'k' )
axes.set_aspect( 1 ) 
plt.show()
```

[image]